# How to setup Multiple Environment (Dev,stage,Prod) using Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, devops

I have a scenario where I am given a AWS instance ( Production, staging, testing), a Docker for development and need to work on a infrastructure work flow. We also need to take care of continuous deployment and integration using Jenkins.

Can you please help me out to figure out a rigid Work flow to create an environment with the above Tech space.

Answer (score 0):

Man, with these tools it is possible to do a lot of different strategies of CI and CD. i recommend to adding GIT and Jenkins in your deck of development tools.

Start doing it in a simple way, first build you application then create new docker images and deliver this in a dev server, then think in how to deliver 
 to others envs.
After that store this images in a private repository using nexus or similar and try to think about an hierarchy of images (base images to app and ready images).

It all depends on your goals.